# How to collect records in crystal report using record selection formula to concatenate records

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

### What i want is to collect records using record selection formula on the basis of criteria selection.

> If i have 2 criteria's then i have 4 combinations using criteria
>   selection. e.g.
>
> if(cri1 <> 'ALL'  and cri2 <> 'ALL') then record fetched 
>  
>         else if(cri1 =  'ALL'  and  cri2 <> 'ALL') then record fetched 
>         else if(cri <> 'ALL'  and cri = 'ALL') then record fetched 
>         else if(cri =  'ALL'  ; cri = 'ALL') then record fetched
>
> (cri1 and cri2 are parameter fields used in crystal report)
>
> In the same way for 3 criteria's, i will have 8 combinations. That is,
>   for n criteria's i will be having '2' to the power of 'n' combinations
>   That means for 10 criteria's i will be having 2 to the power of 10
>   combinations (i.e. 1024) combinations.
>
> Well i want to know whether is there any way to collect data in much
>   simpler way for n number of criteria's. Because for more than 3
>   criteria's it will be very confusing to collect the records.
>
> ** Please help on this..**

Comment: Is there any one who can answer my query ???

Comment: @Waqar Please give me an example on which i can start.. Also which should i try i am unable to understand. Could u please elaborate the same.

Comment: From where do you get these critereias? are these from database or any hardcoded values?

Comment: I am getting the values from the database.

Comment: I have idea but that works only for static data but not for any dynamic data like field from database. I afraid to say I couldn't able to answer your question :(. If you have a satatic data let me know will share my thought.

Comment: I have a static field also as a criteria/parameter to be used. Please tell ..

Comment: How do i use custom function for it... give idea..

Comment: I am sorry to say the logic I tried locally but didn't work.

Comment: Well i have tried for a solution.. and think it will work for n number of criteria's : (if({?cri1} <> "ALL") then {db_value} = {?cri1} else {db_value} = {db_value}); (if({?cri2} <> "ALL") then {db_value} = {?cri2} else {db_value} = {db_value}); and so on. <b>Note :</b> I am joining the result of both the conditions here.