# How to write custom function in crystal report to be used for record selection

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am confused in writing custom function in crystal report to fetch record using record selection.

When we create formula in record selection it will add where clause in the generated SQL-Query on the basis of parameters used. Now i want to write the custom formula, which will extract the record pro-grammatically :

Even i have written a function :

```
Function (stringVar st)(
   stringVar selection; 
   if (st <> 'ALL') then (
        selection = st;
    )
    else(
        //In this case the user select only single value, it will fetch the result to that                //particular column value in the table.. otherwise it leaves that particular row..
        selection = "multiple selection";

    )
)
```

Now the code to use the custom function in record selection using select expert would be :

```
 if(myfunction({?parameter1}) <> "ALL") then
    (
        // what code should i write to select that particular record...
        if(myfunction({?parameter2})) <> "ALL" ) then
        (
            //do selection from the previously selection of rows which have this parameter
             if(myfunction({?parameter3}) <> "ALL") then
             (
                 //do selection from the previously selection of rows which have this 
                 //parameter
             )
             else (//do something else) 
        )
        else (//do something else)
    )
    else (//do something else)
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Please tag your question with 'crystal-reports' and a second tag that represents its version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom function for this.  Assuming that you have two string parameters, ry:

```
// assumes you have a parameter value of 'All Countries' w/ a value of '0'
( '0' IN {?CountryCodes} OR {table.CountryCode} IN {?CountryCodes} )
// assumes you have a parameter value of 'All Regions' w/ a value of '0'
AND ( '0' IN {?RegionCodes} OR {table.RegionCode} IN {?RegionCodes} )
```

Comment: Actually, in my crystal report i have 8 parameters to use with.. and that would be confusing to use the above conditions.. that's why i was using custom function.. Please see this Question also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487960/how-to-collect-records-in-crystal-report-using-record-selection-formula-to-conca